# Error whilst creating script to see what date each folder is created - File Structure

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, file-structure

I am trying to show what folders were created and modified in the test folder. However, I am getting the error: 'IOSamples,DirectoryUTCTime.SetCreationTime(string,System.DateTime)' must declare a body because it is not marked abstract, extern or partial.

Also, if I ignore the error, it runs for 1 second and closes. Not sure why?

```
 using System;
 using System.IO;
 using System.Collections;

 namespace IOSamples
 {
    public class DirectoryUTCTime
    {
       public static void SetCreationTime(
       string path,
       DateTime creationTime
       );
          public static void Main()
          {
            // Set the directory.
            string n = @"H:\Test";
            //Create two variables to use to set the time.
            DateTime dtime1 = new DateTime(2002, 1, 3);
            DateTime dtime2 = new DateTime(1999, 1, 1);

            //Create the directory.
            try
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(n);
            }
            catch (IOException e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e);
            }

            //Set the creation and last access times to a variable DateTime value.
            Directory.SetCreationTime(n, dtime1);
            Directory.SetLastAccessTimeUtc(n, dtime1);

            // Print to console the results.
            Console.WriteLine("Creation Date: {0}", Directory.GetCreationTime(n));
            Console.WriteLine("UTC creation Date: {0}", Directory.GetCreationTimeUtc(n));
            Console.WriteLine("Last write time: {0}", Directory.GetLastWriteTime(n));
            Console.WriteLine("UTC last write time: {0}", Directory.GetLastWriteTimeUtc(n));
            Console.WriteLine("Last access time: {0}", Directory.GetLastAccessTime(n));
            Console.WriteLine("UTC last access time: {0}", Directory.GetLastAccessTimeUtc(n));

            //Set the last write time to a different value.
            Directory.SetLastWriteTimeUtc(n, dtime2);
            Console.WriteLine("Changed last write time: {0}", Directory.GetLastWriteTimeUtc(n));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It closes when `Main()` finishes with no further work to do. If you want it to remain open then add `Console.ReadKey();` at the end.

Comment: Remove `public static void SetCreationTime(string path, DateTime creationTime);`

Comment: What were you trying to do with the `void` named `SetCreationTime` that you declare at the top? I don't understand its purpose.

Comment: @Equalsk after trying the 2 things johnny and you suggested.. it works but I agree it doesn’t show what I want. I want a script that shows what folders/sub folders/files have been created throughout the month.